# C# can implement without class declare as Java

Tags: c#

Java can implement interface OnCustomEventListener such as:

```
classA.setCustomEventListener(new OnCustomEventListener(){
public void onEvent(){
   //do whatever you want to do when the event is performed.
}
```

Does C# can do the same?

Comment: No, there are no anonymous inner classes in C# - but usually you'd use a lambda expression for the same purpose.

Comment: @JonSkeet how about this `var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };`

Comment: @Desperado, although you could pass an anonymous `object` to a method, it would be pretty much useless.

Comment: @Desperado you can't implement interfaces with anonymous classes in C#

Comment: @Desperado: That's not an anonymous inner class in the same way that Java has them. Anonymous types and anonymous inner classes only share the fact that they're anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C# has no direct equivalent to that code, howeever the typical way you would pass some "action" or "callback" to a method would be using a delegate, or the shorter-formed Lambda expression.

```
classA.SetCustomEventListener( () => {
   //do whatever you want to do when the event is performed.
});
```

The code for that method would look like

```
public void SetCustomEventListener (Action action)
{
    action(); // execute the Lambda passed in
}
```

Ref:

- [`Action` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx)